# Does coefficient-wise limit preserve real-rootedness?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $P_n$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ be polynomials with real roots only (and real coefficients), and $P_n$ converge to a non-zero polynomial $Q$ coefficient-wise. Does it follow that $Q$ has real roots only?

This is true if degrees of $P_n$ are uniformly bounded, by Rouché's theorem for example. I expect the answer to be negative in the general case, but do not see an immediate counterexample.

Comment: This type of convergence, can it be seen as the same as for the Laguerre-Polya class? https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/belyaev/papers/polya.pdf

Comment: @PerAlexandersson it is a different topology

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true that the limit polynomial $Q$ has all zeros real.
Moreover, it is true that under your conditions $P_n\to Q$ uniformly on compact subsets of the plane.

Consider first the case that $Q(0)\neq 0$. Then $P_n(0)\neq 0$ for large $n$, and
we have
$$P_n(z)=c_n\prod_k\left(1-\frac{z}{z_{k,n}}\right),$$
$$\left(\frac{P_n^\prime}{P_n}\right)^\prime(0)=-\sum\frac{1}{z_{k,n}^2}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (1).$$
Since $P_n(0)\to Q(0)\neq 0$, the LHS is bounded (and tends to a finite limit). But the summands in the right hand side are all positive, since all $z_{n,k}$ are real. Thus
$$\sum_k\frac{1}{|z_{k,n}|^2}\leq C$$
where $C$ does not depend on $n$. Under these conditions, $P_n$ form a normal family in the whole plane, see for example the book of B. Ya. Levin, Distribution of zeros of
entire functions, Chap VIII, Sect 1, Lemma 1.
So one can choose a subsequence such that $P_n\to P$, where $P$ is an entire function, and since uniform convergence on compacts implies coefficientwise convergence, we conclude that $P=Q$.

Now consider the case that $Q(0)=0$. Since $Q\neq 0$, choose
the smallest $m$ such that $Q^{(m)}(0)\neq 0$. Then we evidently have
$$P_n^{(m)}\to Q^{(m)}$$
coefficientwise, and $f_n:=P_n^{(m)}$ are real polynomials with all zeros real, since this class of polynomials is closed under differentiation.
But this time $f(0):=Q^{(m)}(0)\neq 0$, and we can apply the argument of Laguerre from the previous paragraph. It gives that $f_n\to f=Q^{(m)}$ uniformly on compacts in the plane, and integrating this $m$ times from zero with initial conditions $P_n(0),P_n^\prime(0),...P_{m-1}(0)$ we conclude that $P_n\to Q$ uniformly on compacts
in the plane. This clearly implies that all zeros of $Q$ are real.

Comment: I am confused: why we have two product formulae for $P_n$, one without exponents and one with exponents?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: after the misprint is corrected, you see that the formula is the same.

Comment: How do we conclude that $z_k$ is a finite sequence?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: I proved that $P_n$ converges (to something) uniformly on compact subsets in the plane. This implies coefficientwise convergence, therefore the limit of $P_n$ is $Q$. And since $Q$ is a polynomial, the limit sequence of zeros is finite (Hurwitz thm). I edited my answer to make the logic clearer.

Comment: Ah, so these two parts of the proof should be exchanged? (Actually, I do not see where we use that the sequence $z_k$ is finite.)

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: we do not use that the sequence is finite. If a sequence of real real-rooted polynomials converges coefficientwise to a non-zero power series, then this limit series converges in the whole plane and the convergence is uniform on compacts. All possible limits have been explicitly described and this is called the Laguerre-Polya class.